# counting the difference in bits when comparing two numbers in Lua

Tags: lua, bit-manipulation, octal, hammingweight

I would like to compare two numbers to determine the number of bits which must be flipped in order make them equal.

For instance, 5 and 6 would require 2 bit flips.

I can do this manually, but would like to write a Lua function to do it for me such as:

```
function (a,b)
  return hammingweight of a xor b
end
```

I'm only interested in comparing octals to octals (heheh), so the function would return a value 0-3. Is there an efficient/elegant way to do this that would be better than using a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`bit32`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.7) library introduced in Lua 5.2 makes this process rather simple.

```
local bxor, band, rshift = bit32.bxor, bit32.band, bit32.rshift
local function ham(a, b)
  a = bxor(a, b)
  b = 0 -- Reuse b to count one bits.
  while a > 0 do
    b = b + band(a, 1)
    a = rshift(a, 1)
  end
  return b
end

print(ham(5,6)) -- 2
```

However, if you're only comparing numbers in a small enough range, such as that of `0` to `7`, you could simply precompute and save the results.

```
local bxor = bit32.bxor
local hamcache = {[0] = 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3}
local function ham(a, b)
  return hamcache[bxor(a, b)]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you read through the function in the following link you will see that if you have an array of each octal digit, and the binary representation, then use the gsub function to replace each digit in the octal representation with the binary one.

http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2002-10/msg00244.html

For gsub you may want to look at http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial

Once you have that, loop through each character and see if they differ and mark to chsnge that position.

Comment: This is a thoughtful solution-- it works great! but If I'm going to be making a table of octal representations for reference, I may as well make a 28 character table to describe each comparison directly and use that instead...

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to do this:

1. check the rightmost bit, i.e. check if both numbers are even or odd. If one is and the other is not, this bit is different, so add 1 to the weight sum.
2. Shift 1 bit to the right (either using `bit32.rshift(number, 1)` or by taking integer result of division by 2).
3. If number is 0, you're done otherwise repeat at 1.

Comment: The question should be, is it fast enough for your needs. And I'm 99.9% positive that it is. And of course an algorithmic solution is always cooler then a simple lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

```
local function octal_ham(a, b)
  local x = bit32.bxor(a, b)
  return x - math.floor(x/2) - math.floor(x/4)
end
```

Comment: Playing code golf, I see.  I like the approach, I just don't fully understand how it works. Thanks!